# Laravel 5.5 - Transfer file to S3

Tags: laravel

I have an array of filenames that looks like this

```
array (
'file1.jpg',
'file2.jpg',
'file3.jpg'
)
```

I am trying to loop through them and upload them to an S3 bucket like this..

```
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    Storage::disk('s3')->put(

        /* S3 */
        's3foldername/' . $foldername . '/' . $filename,

        /* Local Storage */
        storage_path('localfolder/' . $foldername . '/' . $filename),
        'public'
    );
}
```

This isn't working for some reason, the paths all check out ok.  Do I need to read the file contents first?

Answer (score 0):

**Storage::put()** method takes either **file content** or a **resource handle** as its second argument - see the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files

In your case, the following should do the trick:

```
 Storage::disk('s3')->put(
    's3foldername/' . $foldername . '/' . $filename,
    file_get_contents(storage_path('localfolder/' . $foldername . '/' . $filename)),
    'public'
);
```

It's just one of the options - see the docs for more.